# Unable to install CASdatasets in r

Tags: r, github, dependencies, devtools, repo

I am not able to install the CASdatasets library r, i have tried several methods but the installation keeps failling

i have tried the following

1. install.packages("CASdatasets", repos = "http://cas.uqam.ca/pub/", type="source")
2. install.packages('CASdatasets', repos ="http://dutangc.free.fr/pub/", type="source")
3. library(devtools)
   devtools::install_github("dutangc/CASdatasets", subdir="pkg")

For the first two i have this error
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
download from 'http://cas.uqam.ca/pub/src/contrib/CASdatasets_1.0-11.tar.gz' failed

The last one also gives an error message
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  :
download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/dutangc/CASdatasets/tarball/HEAD' failed

Comment: i have also seen on another page that someone install it manually. if possible i will like to know how.

Comment: try `remotes::install_github("dutangc/CASdatasets/pkg")` ?

Comment: @BenBolker i just dit. i have the same error messeage.                  Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/dutangc/CASdatasets/tarball/HEAD' failed

Answer (score 0):

If you download the file http://cas.uqam.ca/pub/src/contrib/CASdatasets_1.0-11.tar.gz and run

```r
install.packages("CASdatasets_1.0-11.tar.gz")
```

(assuming the downloaded file is in your working directory, or use `install.packages(file.choose())` to navigate to it interactively) that should work ...

Comment: I have just tried and i have an error message which says that the package is not avialable for my version of r. the version i am using is 4.2.0

Comment: I have just tried from RGUI and it worked. Thanks for your assistance